# Select one record based on results from multiple rows

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have two tables:

```
|  conversations  |      |    conversation_participants   |
-------------------      ----------------------------------
| id | project_id |      | id | conversation_id | user_id |
-------------------      ----------------------------------
  1  | 1                   1  | 1               | 1
  2  | 1                   2  | 1               | 2
                           3  | 2               | 1
                           4  | 2               | 3
```

I need to select the conversation id that two users have in common for a specific project id

So in this example:

- the conversation id that user_id 1 and user_id 2 have in common for project_id 1 is: **1**
- the conversation id that user_id 1 and user_id 3 have in common for project_id 1 is: **2**

I need a query where I can give user_id a, user_id b, and project_id and get a conversation id in return.

I tried something like :

```
SELECT
c.id
FROM conversations c
JOIN conversation_participants p ON p.conversation_id = c.id
WHERE (p.user_id = ? AND c.project_id = ?)
OR (p.user_id = ? AND c.project_id = ?)
```

but of course this returns multiple rows and its probably wrong because in some cases it will return records with different conversation ids...

Help appreciated! Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   SELECT
    c.id
   FROM conversations c
   JOIN conversation_participants p ON p.conversation_id = c.id
   JOIN conversation_participants p2 ON p2.conversation_id = p.conversation_id
   WHERE  c.project_id = ?
   AND p.user_id = ? and p2.user_id = ?
```

you can give:

```
p.user_id = 1   --as user1
p2.user_id = 2  --as user2
c.project_id = 1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/992df/19)